# Readline include conditional statement to skip first column and first header if it matches a file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, if-statement, readline

based on the syntax below, is there a way I can include a if-else statement if the filename matches (e.g. Data/testfile.csv) and I need to skip the first row and first column to read the file?"

```
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python test.py <filename>")
        sys.exit(1)
    inf = open(sys.argv[1])
    data = np.array(
        [list(map(float, s.strip().split(","))) for s in inf.readlines()]
    )
```

Comment: The first column can be skipped if you take not everything `split(',')` returns: `....split(',')[int(inf == 'Data/testfile.csv'):]`. As for the rows, you already skip one at `readlines()`. The syntax is similar. However, this makes the code unreadable. You better introduce variables that store how many columns and rows to skip and assign them accordingly.

Comment: Apoglogies I have removed the [1:]. What happens is that there are multiple files to read and I am trying to include a if scenario if it matches a filename that requires the readline to skip the first row and first column, it can do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```py
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python test.py <filename>")
        sys.exit(1)
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:
        skip_columns = int(inf == 'Data/testfile.csv')  # or another condition
        skip_rows = int(inf == 'Data/testfile.csv')  # or another condition
        data = np.array(
            [list(map(float, s.strip().split(",")[skip_columns:]))
             for s in inf.readlines()[skip_rows:]]
        )
```

By the way, `numpy` has [`loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) and [`genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) functions. They have `skiprows`/`skip_header` and `usecols` parameters and might be of help.

Comment: Thanks, I think there's a typo error there. [skip:columns:]))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @StSav012 for the pointer. It led me to this solution as shown below.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                            
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python testlearner.py <filename>")
        sys.exit(1)
    inf = open(sys.argv[1])
    if (sys.argv[1] == 'Data/testfile.csv'):
        data = np.array(
            [list(map(float, s.strip().split(",")[1:])) for s in inf.readlines()[1:]]
        )
    else:
        data = np.array(
            [list(map(float, s.strip().split(","))) for s in inf.readlines()]
        )
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the file afterwards. Or better use `with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf: if ... else: ...`.